# patchelf - stat: No such file or directory

Tags: gcc, glibc

We are trying to solve below issue :

> INFO | jvm 2 | 2022/04/05 09:06:23.421 | Caused by:
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
> /home/usr/examples/tmp/.djl.ai/pytorch/1.9.1-cpu-linux-x86_64/0.14.0-cpu-libdjl_torch.so:
> /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.23' not found (required by
> /home/usr/examples/tmp/.djl.ai/pytorch/1.9.1-cpu-linux-x86_64/libtorch_cpu.so)

Ran the "strings" command to show what all GLIBC version and could not find "2.23", followed this instruction - https://serverfault.com/questions/894625/safely-upgrade-glibc-on-centos-7 which is we are trying to have GLIBC 2.23 on Centos 7.9, and we were able to complete "make install" using --prefix to use seperate path.

When running this "patchelf" especially this command i am attempting to run :

> patchelf --set-interpreter /opt/glibc-2.23/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
> --set-rpath /opt/glibc-2.23/lib:/usr/lib64 pytorch

I am getting below error where "pytorch" is python module installed :

> stat: No such file or directory

Please advise if anything missed or